# Querydsl: Putting enum constant in a query result

Tags: querydsl

I encountered a use case in which I need to put enum constant in a query result. My query looks like this:

```
QTable qTable = QTable.table;

JPAQuery query = ...

SomeDTO someDTO = query.singleResult(Projections.fields(SomeDTO.class,
                ...,
                someBooleanExpression ? qTable.enumField : <ENUM_CONSTANT>,
                ...));
```

I am looking for a way to put some constant enum value in the place of ENUM_CONSTANT.

I tried Expresssions.as, Expressions.constantAs or EnumTemplate in various combinations, but none of them worked. I think there must be a simple way to fix this, but I just don't know how.

I'm looking for something like:

```
(MyEnum.MyValue).as("enumField")
```

Comment: Approaching the problem for another angle, could you use `coalesce` in your select list, so that by the time the code calls `singleResult`, `enumField` already has the correct value?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try the `CaseBuilder`

```
Expression<MyEnum> cases = new CaseBuilder()
    .when(someBooleanExpression).then(qTable.enumField)
    .otherwise(MyEnum.ENUM_CONSTANT);
```

see [reference](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.5.1/reference/html_single/#d0e2037)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: `com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.Expressions.constant(T value)`